# Gnome-software 'Sorry, something went wrong: the name :n.nnnn was not provided by any .service files'

Tags: 20.04, gnome, gnome-software

When opening gnome software and clicking the update icon, then these errors show up.

Should I ignore it?

[image: error1]

[image: error2]

**EDIT 2021-12-21**: None of the answers below seems to work.

Comment: I am seeing a similar error since quite a while, though it's "The name :1.109 was not provided by any .service files" in my case. I also find this bug with more details in the syslog:
systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.service: Succeeded.
systemd[1]: Finished Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
gnome-software[4331]: not GsPlugin error FwupdError:10: The name :1.109 was not provided by any .service files
gnome-software[4331]: not handling error failed for action refresh: The name :1.109 was not provided by any .service files
…and this repeats 2 more times.

Answer (score 8):

This command solve the issue:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-software
```

I put it as an answer here for improving the visibility of [hosford42 comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1357359/gnome-software-sorry-something-went-wrong-the-name-xxx-was-not-provided-by-an#comment2372546_1359555). All credits to him.

Comment: Reinstalling `gnome-software` solves the issue for a short time, but you still have to issue this command again after a while.

Comment: Only a more explicit `sudo apt autoremove gnome-software && sudo apt install gnome-software` seems to have worked for me (and now I wonder where I found it but surely wasn't my idea :) )

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be an issue on several distros (Zorin, RedHat, Arch...). Based on [this post](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/6695751):

```sh
sudo apt clean 
sudo du -sh /var/cache/apt/ && sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/
pkill gnome-software; pkcon refresh force
```

`pkcon` comes with [PackageKit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/PackageKit) ([`packagekit-tools`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/packagekit-tools)package), a distro-agnostic alternative to `apt`.

Comment: This solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
sudo apt install policykit-1
```

It might help.

Comment: Didn't work :( , thanks anyway for answering. But if no one can my answer then you get the bounty for answering my question.

Comment: The error means that the gnome-software app is not connecting to a file that helps populate some if not all the software inside the window dialog.

Do you have any apps installed thru Flatpak?
If yes do;

            #$ flatpak list

This will show you a list of apps installed thru flatpak
In my case;
org.audacityteam.Audacity/x86_64/stable

so the NAME will be; org.audacityteam.Audacity
so! run;

#$flatpak update NAME

FOR EACH APP

if not then try to reinstall gnome-software to allow it to regain access to the right links, if that makes any sense!

Comment: `sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-software` seems to have done the trick.

Comment: @hosford42 that solved the problem for me --- you should add this as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

If the problem its with the flatpak apps maybe you can try to run:

```
sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-flatpak
```